# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch while using Reflection

Tags: java, reflection

Below is my code from which I am using reflection to call a method but I am always getting
exception

```
List<PdAttrKey> attrKeys = new ArrayList<PdAttrKey>();
Properties adapterProps = new Properties();

PdReadRequest pdReadRequest = new PdReadRequest(1L, 1L, (short) 0, new Date(),
dataDurationSec, 2L, 3L, attrKeys, null, adapterProps);

PdAdapterUserReadOnlyGemsReader adapter1 = new PdAdapterUserReadOnlyGemsReader();

PdReader reader = adapter1.acquireReader(pdReadRequest);

UserCacheDoImpl userDos = Some Value;

Method method = getClassMethod("createPdRecordFromUserDO");

// This line is throwing me exception. And I don't know why?
PdRecord onePdsxRecord = (PdRecord) method.invoke(reader, userDos);
```

This is the below method from which I am getting all the method names of a class.

```
    private Method getClassMethod(String methodName) {
        Method method = null;

        Method[] methodList = PdAdapterUserReadOnlyGemsReader.PdUserReadOnlyGemsReader.class
                .getDeclaredMethods();
        for (Method m : methodList) {
            if (m.getName().equals(methodName)) {
                method = m;
                method.setAccessible(true);
                break;
            }
        }

        return method;
    }
```

Some More Code:-

```
private PdRecord createPdRecordFromUserDO(UserCacheDoImpl userCache) {
   // Some code here
}
```

This is the exception I am getting. Any idea why?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
```

Any suggestions will be of great help.

Comment: Can you show the method `PdReader.createPdsxRecordFromUserDO()`? Does it takes only one argument, the same type of `userDos`?

Comment: And what's the type of `userDos`? You've given us irrelevant information (how you're fetching the method, and setup stuff) but not the *crucial* information about the method you're trying to call and what you're calling it with.

Comment: Sorry for not posting the other code. I just updated the question with other code as well. let me know if I need to provide other information as well.

Comment: Is `reader` an instance of `PdUserReadOnlyGemsReader`?

Comment: Can you show a short but complete example which demonstrates the problem? Basically there's still a lot of extraneous code here, but not enough for us to actually reproduce it. Are there multiple methods with the same name, by the way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please check if more than one method with name "createPdRecordFromUserDO" exists.
It looks like there are more than one, but with different arguments.

Your method getClassMethod returns the first method it finds, but that could be the wrong one.
Check if methodList.length > 1, then this is the cause of the bug.

Rethink what you want to do if multiple methods with the given name are found.

Comment: Further the code looks a bit of a hack, because you set the method to accessible, where it eventually was meant to be private. This line (method.setAccessible(true) may fail with an Exception if the security setting of the JVM is set to higher value than standard.

Comment: If that did not solve your problem, and when methodList.length == 1, then check the full qualified name of UserCacheDoImpl: Are both from the same package. Example com.foo1.UserCacheDoImpl in your code, while the method may need a com.foo2.UserCacheDoImpl. Print out the full qualified argument name. (I think Class.getCanonicalName() )