# Argument type mismatch: IllegalArgumentException on simple case

Tags: java, reflection, illegalargumentexception

I have this famous problem about IllegalArgumentException, and I cannot figure out why. Here is my class:

```
  public class DataMapper   {
          ... An lot of others methods that does not have the same name (because I created a method specifically for checking this exception

          private void hello(String ahem)   {
              logger.info("Hey !");
          }
}
```

In my test case (where I try to invoke my method):

```
 @Test
    public void test()  {
       Class<?> targetClass = DataMapper.class;

       try    {
           Object t = targetClass.newInstance();

           Class<?>[] cArg = new Class[1];
           cArg[0] = String.class;

           Method method = targetClass.getDeclaredMethod("hello", cArg);
           method.setAccessible(true);
           method.invoke(t, cArg);
      }   catch(NoSuchMethodException e)   {
            logger.error("Name does not exist : ", e);
            Assert.fail();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("It is broken : ", e);
            Assert.fail();
        }
   }
```

It always falls on an IllegalArgumentException. The `Method` object sounds to agree with my expectations, tho:

[image: Arguments of the method]

[image: My argument's array]

Any ideas what is happening there ?
Before any duplication flags, I already checked those, and nothing is exactly the same, nor works:

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438369/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-argument-type-mismatch-while-using-reflectio) constructs a list of methods, fact was he had 2 or more methods with the same name, but not the same arguments.
[The second one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36447647/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-argument-type-mismatch-on-string-array) was in mistake because he was passing a String[] as the arguments, and the compiler was misinterpreting the object for the full arguments list.
[The third one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24387242/java-argument-type-mismatch-while-reflection) was because he forgot to pass an argument.

Comment: Please include the stacktrace of the exception (and include the exception message)

Comment: You're trying to pass a `Class` reference as an argument to a method that accepts a `String`. You need to differentiate between "the parameter types used to find the right method" and "the argument values used to invoke the method".

Comment: That settled the problem, thanks Jon. I thought you had to pass classes to the `invoke` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
method.invoke(t, cArg);
```

You must pass a `String` as instead of `cArg` which is an array of `Class`. Something like the following will work:

```
method.invoke(t, "Test");
```